# Round numbers to the nearest zero

Tags: r

I have two pattern of numbers:

```
x1 = 0.0003577
x2 = 0.2365483
```

How can I round them to be like:

```
x1 = 0.00035
x2 = 0.23
```

so only two or one number after the last zero after comma appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a user function `f` like below

```
f <- function(x) {
  p <- 10^(-ceiling(log10(x)) + 2)
  trunc(x * p) / p
}
```

and you will get

```
> f(x1)
[1] 0.00035

> f(x2)
[1] 0.23
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use `signif` in the `base` package. The function rounds the values in its first argument to the specified number of significant digits.

```
x1 = 0.0003577
x2 = 0.2365483

#where 2 is the number of significant digit
signif(x1,2)
[1] 0.00036
signif(x2,2)  
[1] 0.24
```

Comment: Thanks. but I wanted to get exactly the same numbers. e.g. x1=0.00035.

Comment: This is the best way to do it.  0.00036 is correctly rounded.  0.00035 is just truncated by discarding digits, but doing that will introduce bias.